# Theorem/Example numbering in LaTeX

Tags: numbering, theorems, counters

I want Theorem/Example with the following numbers:

```
Theorem 1.1.
Example 1.2.1.
Example 1.2.2.
Theorem 1.3.
```

However, I am only able to obtain:

```
Theorem 1.1.
Example 1.1.1.
Example 1.1.2.
Theorem 1.2.
```

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[thm]

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{thm}
\end{thm}

\begin{exmp}
\end{exmp}

\begin{exmp}
\end{exmp}

\begin{thm}
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will there always be two or more examples per theorem? What should be done if there's just one example: Should it be labeled as "1.2.1" of as "1.2"?

Comment: If there is only one example, then it should be labeled as "1.2.1".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following solution employs the `etoolbox` package and its `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` macro. Specifically, the additional preamble code shown below serves to step the `thm` counter at the start of an `exmp` environment if one of the following two conditions is true:

- A `thm` environment was executed recently, i.e., somewhere before the occurrence of an `exmp` environment. In contrast, if the current `exmp` environment is preceded by another `exmp` environment, the `thm` counter is not stepped.
- The `exmp` environment occurs *before* a `thm` environment occurs within the current section.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[thm]

%% start of new code block
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for '\BeforeBeginEnvironment' macro
\newif\ifThmRecent\ThmRecenttrue % initiate the conditional
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{thm}{\ThmRecenttrue} % set to 'true'
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{exmp}{%
   \ifThmRecent 
       \ThmRecentfalse
       \stepcounter{thm}
   \else 
       \ifnum\value{thm}=0 \stepcounter{thm} \fi
   \fi
}
%% end of new code block

\begin{document}

\section{Uno}
\begin{thm}\end{thm}
\begin{exmp}\end{exmp}
\begin{exmp}\end{exmp}
\begin{thm}\end{thm}

\section{Due}
\begin{thm}\end{thm}
\begin{exmp}\end{exmp}
\begin{thm}\end{thm}

\section{Tre}
\begin{exmp}\end{exmp}
\begin{exmp}\end{exmp}
\begin{thm}\end{thm}

\end{document}
```